# get_comments_number of depth-1 (Level 1) (1 post)

Tags: comments

I selected only 2 levels of comment for my wordpress site.
How can I display the number of comment of the first level ? (Depth-1)

Comment: Where did you select to "use" two levels of comments? Are you trying to retrieve the number of 1st-level comments while ignoring (not counting) all of those beneath the 1st level? Where are you trying to display this number?

Answer (score 2):

In the wp_comments table, if `comment_parent` equals 0, it's a first-level comment.

```
function get_num_toplevel_comments() {
    global $wpdb;

    return $wpdb->get_var("
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM $wpdb->comments
        WHERE comment_parent = 0
    ");
}
```

Comment: @toscho - sorry to comment here, I'm not yet able to comment elsewhere. Your function retrieves all of the top-level comments in their entirety. @ Mathieu specifically asked in two separate places in the question for just the number of top-level comments. Your answer did teach me a new hook though! Virtual +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on [akTed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/25472/akted)'s answer:

```
function get_top_level_comments_number( $post_id = 0, $onlyapproved = true ) {

    global $wpdb, $post;

    $post_id = $post_id ? $post_id : $post->ID;

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE comment_parent = 0 AND comment_post_ID = $post_id";

    if( $onlyapproved ) $sql .= " AND comment_approved='1'";

    return (int) $wpdb->get_var( $sql );

}
```

Usage same as [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_comments_number) … Returns the number of top level comments for a specific post (or the current one if no id is given)

Comment: I add condition for approved and convert to int type

`return (int) $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE comment_parent = 0 AND comment_post_ID = $post_id AND comment_approved='1'" );`

Comment: @kostikovmu Yeah makes totally sense. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code from [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/78491/73) and remove just one `!`:

```
add_filter( 'comments_clauses', 'wpse_78628_top_comments_only' );

$comments = get_comments();

remove_filter( 'comments_clauses', 'wpse_78628_top_comments_only' );

function wpse_78628_top_comments_only( $clauses )
{
    $clauses['where'] .= ' AND comment_parent = 0';
    return $clauses;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic work.:)
worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

here is some full working code, based on previous answers.

```
  <?php
add_filter( 'comments_clauses', 'wpse_78490_child_comments_only' );

function wpse_78490_child_comments_only( $clauses )
{
    $clauses['where'] .= ' AND comment_parent != 0';
    return $clauses;
}
  $count = get_comments( array('post_id' => $post->ID, 'count' => true) ); echo $count; ?>
```