# display only parent replies count in index.php

Tags: loop, customization, comments

Currently my posts display the total count of comments (i.e both replies and sub-comments).

I want to display only the number of reply count in my index.php (and not comments for a reply) for each post i.e. where comment_parent = 0

I have tried different codes but no luck. What's the best way to acheive this?

Comment: @toscho I just went through your answer in a similar question. Am new to wordpress. Can you tell me how do I integrate your code in index.php to show the top-level comment count for each post.

cheers!

Comment: @toscho I tried your code by pasting it in the functions.php but still am getting the count for all the replies and comments instead of just the top-level comments.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I tested this local before I posted it here. It works. Try to collect [debug information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to see if something went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78628/get-comments-number-of-depth-1-level-1-1-post) I suggest the following code:

```
// the theme's functions.php

/**
 * Get the number of top level comments for a post.
 *
 * @param  int $post_id
 * @return int
 */
function wpse_95242_top_level_comments_for_post( $post_id = NULL )
{
    if ( NULL === $post_id )
        $post_id = get_the_ID();

    if ( ! $post_id )
        return 0;

    add_filter( 'comments_clauses', 'wpse_95242_where_top_comments_only' );

    $comments = get_comments(
        array (
            'post_id' => $post_id
        )
    );

    remove_filter( 'comments_clauses', 'wpse_95242_where_top_comments_only' );

    if ( ! $comments )
        return 0;

    return count( $comments );
}

/**
 * Filter comment query for top level comments.
 *
 * @wp-hook comments_clauses
 * @param   array $clauses
 * @return  array
 */
function wpse_95242_where_top_comments_only( $clauses )
{
    $clauses['where'] .= ' AND comment_parent = 0';
    return $clauses;
}
```

In your loop you call the function on each item:

```
printf(
    __( '%d top level comments', 'theme_text_domain' ),
    wpse_95242_top_level_comments_for_post()
);
```